# Should we plan a celebration?

Tags: discussion

SU is rapidly approaching 1/4 million questions.  Shouldn't the person who asks the 250,000th question get some balloons or something?

Comment: or some candies or a discount coupon to 'GetFat'(made-up name) franchise?

Comment: How about [post #1337](http://superuser.com/a/1337/218034)?

Comment: Given that [Travel.SE is doing the same thing](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/competition-when-will-we-hit-10-000-questions) I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Ha ha, and we should have a bet that the 250,000th isn't going to be off topic :)